# Asp.Net C# mvc. Running compiled application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-applications

I realize my question may be something stupid. But here is the problem:
   Ive got an ASP.NET MVC web application, it already compiled and it works on the web host. So it has no *.cs files (as I understand they turned into dlls), and clearly it has no *.sln file. I want to run this application using Visual Studio 17, and try to debug it(to see the real code working and get something useful for myself) is it possible? If yes, then please, tell me how to do this. I'd like to google it and find out, but I don`t even understand what to look for.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you still have the original source code somewhere?

Comment: JetBrains has a free (I think?) tool:  dotPeek .  If I recall, correctly, it will export the classes and such.

Comment: No, I don`t have the original source code.

Comment: The symbols that allow you to debug do not get compiled or run when you compile in release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use  [Disassembler](https://onlinedisassembler.com) only for view a namespaces and clases, but not all the code.

Comment: Ok, I got this solution in google, however I thought there is a way to do this in other way, thanks.